# Insert character inside array data

Tags: node.js, typescript

how to insert character from array?

This my data :

```
["a", "b", "c", ...]
```

i'm wanna change my data like this:

```
["$a", "$b", "$c", ...]
```

Thanks before

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: const newArray = ["a", "b", "c", ...].map(item => '$' + item);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c", ...]
a.map(value => '$'+value) // this will do what you need returns ["$a", "$b", "$c"]
```

**map basically iterate through the array and map each element according to the given condition**

Array.map(value => *map the value with any type of data here*)

Comment: Imho that parameter should be named `value` (or at least not `key`). The "key" would be the index which is the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` - **ES6 way**

[Map mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b']
const modifiedArray = arr.map(el => '$' + el)
console.log(modifiedArray)
```

However note it will modify the original array so if you don't want to modify original `array`

Use `spread` of ES6

[spread mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const modifiedArray = {...arr}.map(el => '$' + el)
```

**Non ES6**

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b'],
  modifiedArr = []
  
for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  modifiedArr.push('$' + arr[i])
}

console.log(modifiedArr)
```